# What can cause Windows to send the ID_HELP command twice

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

In my app, I overrode `CFrameWnd::OnHelp` to open a word doc instead of our old .hlp file.  However, when I press F1, I noticed the function is being executed twice.  I examined the stacks and found that `AfxWndProcBase` is receiving command `0x1E146`, and then `CWnd::OnCommand` is truncating that to `0xE146` when calling `CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg`, and `0xE146` is the `ID_HELP` command.  Then immediately after this, `AfxWndProcBase` is receiving command `0xE146`, and runs the help command again.  After some experimentation, I've discovered that the second message is being received and processed *inside* the call to `AfxMessageBox` when the first message is being processed.

Handler is here:

```
void CMainFrame::OnHelp() {
  BOOL bWorked;
  STARTUPINFO suInfo = {};
  suInfo.cb = sizeof(suInfo);
  PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo = {};
  CString m_Process = _T("Start");
  CString vipx = /*_T("\"") +*/ CString(AfxGetApp()->m_pszHelpFilePath) /*+ _T("\"")*/;

  bWorked = ::CreateProcess(m_Process,
             vipx.GetBuffer(),      // requires non-const :(
             NULL,
             NULL,
             FALSE,
             NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
             NULL,
             NULL,
             &suInfo,
             &procInfo);
  vipx.ReleaseBuffer();

  if (procInfo.dwThreadId==NULL || bWorked==false)
      AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to launch help: " + GetErrNoText(GetLastError())));
  //AfxMessageBox causes my app to receive the message again?

  CloseHandle(procInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(procInfo.hThread);  
}
```

Why are both `0x1E146` and `0xE146` being sent to my app when I press F1 (and what is the first one?)

After a rewrite, I discovered that calling `ShellExecute` also causes the "1 deep recursion".

I have no idea if it's relevent, but here's my form's message map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMainFrame)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
//}}AFX_MSG_MAP
    // Global help commands
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, OnHelp) //F1  <--- both messages are this one?
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

In my resource file I found these, one for F1 and one for Shift+F1:

```
VK_F1,          ID_CONTEXT_HELP,        VIRTKEY, SHIFT, NOINVERT
VK_F1,          ID_HELP,                VIRTKEY, NOINVERT
```

Probably useless, but here's the two callstacks:

```
MyApp.exe!CMainFrame::OnHelp()  Line 66 C++
mfc90ud.dll!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget=0x01fea410, unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void (void)* pfn=0x0040b720, void * pExtra=0x00000000, unsigned int nSig=57, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 82    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 381 + 0x27 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 946 + 0x18 bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 2364   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 366   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0, long * pResult=0x0018fba4)  Line 1769 + 0x1e bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x01fea410, HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 403    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=123206, long lParam=0)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes   C++
    ...
mfc90ud.dll!CFrameWnd::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 249 + 0x1b bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree(HWND__ * hWndStop=0x00160bb4, tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 2946 + 0x14 bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 233 + 0x12 bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 777 + 0x9 bytes C++
MyApp.exe!CCXMyAppApp::PreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 749  C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxPreTranslateMessage(tagMSG * pMsg=0x00712740)  Line 252 + 0x11 bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  Line 178 + 0x18 bytes C++
```

Second message:

```
MyApp.exe!CMainFrame::OnHelp()  Line 66 C++
mfc90ud.dll!_AfxDispatchCmdMsg(CCmdTarget * pTarget=0x01fea410, unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void (void)* pfn=0x0040b720, void * pExtra=0x00000000, unsigned int nSig=57, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 82    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CCmdTarget::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 381 + 0x27 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CFrameWnd::OnCmdMsg(unsigned int nID=57670, int nCode=0, void * pExtra=0x00000000, AFX_CMDHANDLERINFO * pHandlerInfo=0x00000000)  Line 946 + 0x18 bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 2364    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CFrameWnd::OnCommand(unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 366    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0, long * pResult=0x0018e264)  Line 1769 + 0x1e bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x01fea410, HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 403 C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x001703da, unsigned int nMsg=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes    C++
...
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::SendMessageW(unsigned int message=273, unsigned int wParam=57670, long lParam=0)  Line 42 + 0x44 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnHelpInfo(tagHELPINFO * __formal=0x0008c890)  Line 3195  C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632, long * pResult=0x0018e5ec)  Line 1948 + 0xd bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x0253a410, HWND__ * hWnd=0x00160bb4, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x00160bb4, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 403 C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x00160bb4, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes    C++
    ...
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::DefWindowProcW(unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 1043 + 0x20 bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::Default()  Line 274   C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnHelpInfo(tagHELPINFO * __formal=0x0008c890)  Line 3198 + 0x8 bytes  C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::OnWndMsg(unsigned int message=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632, long * pResult=0x0018eb70)  Line 1948 + 0xd bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x0253aa28, HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 403 C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=83, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=575632)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes    C++
    ...
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::DefWindowProcW(unsigned int nMsg=77, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 1043 + 0x20 bytes    C++
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=77, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 1756 + 0x1c bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxCallWndProc(CWnd * pWnd=0x0253aa28, HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=77, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 240 + 0x1c bytes C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=77, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 403  C++
mfc90ud.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd=0x000b08c6, unsigned int nMsg=77, unsigned int wParam=0, long lParam=0)  Line 441 + 0x15 bytes C++
    ...
mfc90ud.dll!CWnd::WindowProc(unsigned int message=7423648, unsigned int wParam=7423712, long lParam=2016221872)  Line 1755 + 0x20 bytes C++
    ...
mfc90ud.dll!AfxDeactivateActCtx(unsigned long dwFlags=0, unsigned long ulCookie=353633777)  Line 260 + 0x17 bytes   C++
mfc90ud.dll!AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2::~AFX_MAINTAIN_STATE2()  Line 63 + 0xe bytes    C++
```

Comment: `CWnd::OnCommand` truncates `wParam` 0x1E146 to `nID` 0xE146 because `nID = LOWORD(wParam)`, so that's ok. Do you get two messages if you replace `AfxMessageBox` by `TRACE`? Also, I don't understand the "+" in the call to `AfxMessageBox`, parameter #1 is a LPCTSTR, so you would need to concatenate the strings before calling `AfxMessageBox`, that would not happen with a "+"

Comment: I haven't tried a `TRACE`, but if I call `ShellExecute` before the `AfxMessageBox`, _that_ gets the second message _instead_.  Very bizarre.  `GetErrNoText` is a function I wrote that returns a `CString`, so `LPCTSTR+CString` does indeed concatenate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ID_HELP is a pre-defined MFC `#define`, if you want to continue using this ID, you would need to have your handler in your CWinApp derived class (see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8874ckw0.aspx)) instead of the Frame-class.

Alternatively, you could replace `ID_HELP` by your own ID (say, `IDM_HELP`) which doesn't conflict with a pre-defined MFC ID, that way you wouldn't get two seperate handlers for the same ID.

Comment: Yes, I'm _trying_ to handle the pre-defined MFC `ID_HELP`, it's not a custom ID.   ....wait... the handler goes in the CWinApp?  Why is my handler code in the CMainFrame?

Comment: This MSDN bug report mentions that MFC can sometimes overload the undocumented `CMainFrame::OnHelp`, which is apperently what confused me: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/411625/no-msdn-documentation-for-mfc-cframewnd-onhelp-or-cmdiframewnd-onhelp.  You helped me find the error!

Answer (score 2):

[Apperently this person found the same issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c82991d-ac7e-4f10-b875-3522dace10c0/f1-key-results-in-two-calls-to-cmainframeonhelp) and talks about the cause and effect.

> This double event handling is due to some legacy code.
>
> Windows automatically translates F1 key into WM_HELP messages since Windows 95 (the support article mentioned by Viorel_). The processing you noticed with the 0x4d message does exactly that; this is some Windows code. Then, when an application receives a WM_HELP message, it (can) handle it by calling WinHelp.
>
> Before Windows 95, WM_HELP message did not exist. The only way to handle F1 was to create a VK_F1 shortcut, and add a handler for it. Windows 95, by adding the WM_HELP message, made the help management easier. Since Win95, you don't have to create a VK_F1 shortcut for ID_HELP anymore.
>
> The MFC Appwizard still adds this shortcut if you select "Context Sensitive Help" option though. MFC are older than Windows 95! If you create an MFC Appwizard application using context sensitive help, a shortcut is created for VK_F1, associated with CFrameWnd::OnHelp(), which routes WM_HELP messages to the frame windows of the application. "So far so good".
>
> But Windows also automatically translate F1 keystroke into WM_HELP messages. So CFrameWnd::OnHelp() is called once again, because WM_HELP event is handled by the MFC.
>
> If you don't want to be called twice, remove the keyboard shortcut in your resource file and handle WM_HELP instead. Then you will have the following process:
>
> - Windows catches F1 key, generates WM_HELP
> - A message handler for WM_HELP (ON_WM_HELPINFO) in your code catches WM_HELP messages. MFC default message processing for WM_HELP is to send a WM_COMMAND(ID_HELP) message (this is another funny part!)
> - A message handler for WM_COMMAND(ID_HELP) in your code calls default MFC processing. This runs winhelp.
>
> The following CMainFrame code doesn't handle twice help messages:
>
> ```
> ON_WM_HELPINFO()
> ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CMDIFrameWndEx::OnHelp)
>
> ..
>
>
> BOOL CMainFrame::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo)
> {
>     return CMDIFrameWndEx::OnHelpInfo(pHelpInfo);
> }
> ```
>
> And don't forget to remove the shortcut for VK_F1 in the resource file!

Don't upvote this post, [follow the link and upvote the origional post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c82991d-ac7e-4f10-b875-3522dace10c0/f1-key-results-in-two-calls-to-cmainframeonhelp)